# Postgres pg_wals full whats best practice for removal of old WALs that were not removed automatically

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

We had an outage on our postgresql-12 server at the weekend, we have pg_wals that reside on a partition that had become full. This then crashed the server due to the space running out.

We then moved the pg_wals to a different partition and started the server up.

I can see new pg_wals are generating but have some dating from a day or so ago which have not cleared.

DB PG Setting:

```
archive_command = on
archive_command = '/home/postgres/bin/walarchiving.bsh %p %f'
wal_keep_segments = 500
```

Can I remove the old WALs that pre-date the new start time of postgres? What is the best practice on old WALs after a PG crash.

Comment: "We then moved the pg_wals to a different partition and started the server up."  Please expand on this.  You moved the whole directory then symlinked to the new location?  You moved some of the files from that directory, but not all of them?

Comment: @jjanes yes sorry, I moved the whole pg_wal directory to a different location and used a symlink. However when starting postgres was fine but the old WALs from the day prior were still there and not clearing down. I could see subsequent new WALs generating/clearing down.

Answer (score 1):

Don't manually delete WAL segments. They get removed automatically if they are no longer needed. If that doesn't happen, something is blocking progress:

- perhaps the archiver is failing
- perhaps you have a stale replication slot

Remove the problem, and PostgreSQL will delete the old files after the next checkpoint.

Comment: am not sure its doing anything now. I do see WALs archiving as the directory the WALs reside in have the most recent time. However there are still old WALs from before the server crashed that are still there is there anyway of seeing if these are used at all? I also see there is no replication slots which could be holding it up.

Comment: If PostgreSQL itself deletes files with a name (not a timestamp) later than your problem files, it is probably safe to delete them. No guarantees; if you want to be sure, let an expert look at this.